# C error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type linked list

Tags: c

In my c program I creating a singly linked list where we have to insert a node using the prev node, I'm getting this error in my `main()` function:

> Dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct Node’

I am not sure why is it giving that error.

`while((temp->next != NULL) && (temp->next->data < randomNumData))` -- error here

```
typedef struct _Node
{       
        int data;
        struct Node *next;
} ListNode;

ListNode *newList();
ListNode *insertNode(ListNode *prev, int data);

int main()
{
        ListNode *head = newList();

        int randomNumData;
        ListNode *temp = head;
        int i;

        for(i = 0; i < 11; i++)
        {
                randomNumData = random()%1001;
                while((temp->next != NULL) && (temp->next->data < randomNumData))
                {
                        temp = temp->next;
                }
                temp->data = randomNumData;
                head = insertNode(temp, randomNumData);
        }

        printList(head);
}

// returning the head of a new list using dummy head node
ListNode *newList()
{
        ListNode *head;
        head = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
        if(head == NULL)
        {
                printf("ERROR");
                exit(1);
        }

        head->next = NULL;
        return head;
}

ListNode *insertNode(ListNode *prev, int data)
{
        ListNode *temp = prev;
        prev->next = temp->next;
        temp->next->data = data;

        return temp;
}
```

Comment: Where do you define `ListNode` and `struct Node`?

Comment: Please provide an example which builds. Where is the definition of `ListNode`?

Comment: `struct Node *next;` --> `struct _Node *next;`

Comment: Sorry, I added the struct for ListNode

Comment: You've declared `struct Node *next;` but there is no `struct Node` defined anywhere.

Comment: missing `printList()`

Comment: inconsistent naming: sometimes `_Node` sometimes `Node`

Comment: @melpomene, wow, I didn't catch that. Thanks. It works now

Comment: You have a `struct _Node`, and you have a `typedef` called `Node`. You do not have a `struct Node` anywhere. Do yourself a favour and lose the `typedef`, it's not adding anything.

Comment: I used typedef so that I don't need to keep writing struct _Node in other functions

Comment: @bubbles2189 It seems that these statements                 temp->data = randomNumData;
                head = insertNode(temp, randomNumData); do not make sense.

Comment: @bubbles2189 The function insertNode has undefined behavior and also does not make sense as its call.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I'm updating my insertNode function to take in two node parameters, prev node and current node, and going to insert based on that. Sorry this is my first time programing in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing underscore when declaring next.

```
typedef struct _Node
{       
    int data;
    struct _Node *next;
} ListNode;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have a struct called Node. Import it from other file or just implement it. C is good but it's not a magician so far.